# CoffeeScript date formatting

Tags: javascript, strings, coffeescript

```
forceTwoDigits = (val) ->
  if val < 10
    return "0#{val}"
  return val

formatDate = (date) ->
  year = date.getFullYear()
  month = forceTwoDigits(date.getMonth()+1)
  day = forceTwoDigits(date.getDate())
  hour = forceTwoDigits(date.getHours())
  minute = forceTwoDigits(date.getMinutes())
  second = forceTwoDigits(date.getSeconds())
  return "#{year}#{month}#{day}#{hour}#{minute}#{second}"

console.log(formatDate(new Date()))
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated:

```
formatDate = (date) ->
  timeStamp = [date.getFullYear(), (date.getMonth() + 1), date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds()].join(" ")
  RE_findSingleDigits = /\b(\d)\b/g

  # Places a `0` in front of single digit numbers.
  timeStamp = timeStamp.replace( RE_findSingleDigits, "0$1" )
  timeStamp.replace /\s/g, ""
```

Comment: Thanks!, I'm not sure doing it all at once is clearer or more maintainable though.

Comment: @VinkoVrsalovic Updated with code comment

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with UTC and your JS env supports it (you can use a [shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) if it doesn't), you can do it as a one liner:

```
formatDate = (date) -> date.toISOString().replace /\..+$|[^\d]/g, ''
```

If you want it in the local timezone, it's a little more code:

```
formatDate = (date) ->
  normalisedDate = new Date(date - (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000))
  normalisedDate.toISOString().replace /\..+$|[^\d]/g, ''
```